# How to calculate a percentage score for a quiz in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a quiz in Javascript and should output an score in HTML. The user is prompted the quiz questions and afterwards, their score should be outputted into an HTML file.

I have the questions working perfectly, however I want to get the score calculated as a percentage.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
// Declare the "score" variable
var score = 0;
// Create the questions array
var questions = [
["T or F: Two plus two is ten."],
["T or F: George Washington was the first U.S.president."],
["T or F: Al Gore is our current Vice President."],
["T or F: Two plus two is four."],
["T or F: You are not an alien from Mars."]
];
// Create the answer key array
var answer_key = [
["F"],
["T"],
["F"],
["T"],
["T"]
];
// Ask each question
function askQuestion(question) {
  var answer = prompt(question[0], "");
  if (answer.toUpperCase() == answer_key[i]) {
    alert("Correct!");
    score++;
  } else if (answer==null || answer=="") {
    alert("You must enter T or F!");
    i--;
  } else {
    alert("Sorry. The correct answer is " + answer_key[i]);
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  askQuestion(questions[i]);
}

// Caclulate score
function scoreTest(answer, questions) {
var score = (answer/questions) * 100;
return score;
}
```

Here is the HTML code in which the output should display:

```
<script>
var message = "Your score for the test is " + scoreTest(answer, questions);
document.write("<p>" + message + "</p>")
</script>
```

If the output/function were working, it should display "Your score for the test is 80%", assuming 4/5 questions were answered correctly for example.

Comment: `answer_key[i]` whats inseide the `i`?

Comment: you should pass scoreTest() the score and the question count.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `score` stores the number of correct answers of a total of five. Which means the percentage is `store * 20`. Your `scoreTest` function is dividing a string by an array, which will not work. All you need is `var message = "Your score for the test is " + (score * 20) + "%.";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the arguments score and questions.length to calculate the percentage where as you only passed variable names in the `scoretest` function.
Your code

```
scoreTest(answer, questions);
```

What it should be

```
scoreTest(score, questions.length);
```

```js
// Declare the "score" variable
var score = 0;
// Create the questions array
var questions = [
["T or F: Two plus two is ten."],
["T or F: George Washington was the first U.S.president."],
["T or F: Al Gore is our current Vice President."],
["T or F: Two plus two is four."],
["T or F: You are not an alien from Mars."]
];
// Create the answer key array
var answer_key = [
["F"],
["T"],
["F"],
["T"],
["T"]
];
// Ask each question
function askQuestion(question) {
  var answer = prompt(question[0], "");
  if (answer.toUpperCase() == answer_key[i]) {
    alert("Correct!");
    score++;
  } else if (answer==null || answer=="") {
    alert("You must enter T or F!");
    i--;
  } else {
    alert("Sorry. The correct answer is " + answer_key[i]);
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  askQuestion(questions[i]);
}

// Caclulate score
function scoreTest(answer, questions) {
var score = (answer/questions) * 100;
return score;
}
var message = "Your score for the test is " + scoreTest(score, questions.length);
document.write("<p>" + message + "%</p>")
```

Comment: already did `document.write("<p>" + message + "%</p>")
 Run code snippet`

Answer (score 0):

The numerator to calculate the score should be the number of questions answered correctly. The denominator should be the total number of questions.

The number of questions answered correctly is `score`.
The total number of questions is `questions.length`.

So your code can look like:

```
let message = `Your score for the test is ${(score / questions.length) * 100}%`;
document.write(`<p>${message}</p>`);
```

Note that this code needs to come after `questions` and `score` have been declared, and the scoring has occurred.